# Javascript-Given an array, swap first and last, third and third-to-last, etc

Tags: javascript, arrays

The idea is to have the following input/output:

- input would be ['true',42,'Ada',2,'pizza'] and output would be ['pizza',42,'Ada',2,'true'];
- for input [1,2,3,4,5,6], output would be [6,2,4,3,5,1]

Here is the code I currently have:

```
function swapTowardsTheCenter(array) {

var len = array.length;
var idx = 0;
var lastIdx = array.length -1;

while (idx<=len/2 && lastIdx>=len/2) {
    var temp = array[idx];
    array[idx] = array[lastIdx];
    array[lastIdx] = temp;
    idx = idx + 2;
    lastIdx = lastIdx - 2;

}

return array;

}
```

Could anyone please help me find my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: It returns your desired output for both inputs you supplied..?

Comment: I've tried your code, the sample io works fine. what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Make a copy of the array (using `array.slice()`) before mutating it. I’m assuming some code challenge website is telling you that your code is working incorrectly and that’s likely what’s wrong.

Comment: Oh! Now I see it works with the desired output. So sorry everyone! I was getting a different results with random arrays, but it seems to be working now. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate of your code, but does same thing.

```
function swapTowardsTheCenter(arr) {
    var len = arr.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < Math.floor(len/2); i+=2 ) {
        var sw = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[len - 1 - i];
        arr[len - 1 - i] = sw;
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(swapTowardsTheCenter(['true',42,'Ada',2,'pizza']));
console.log(swapTowardsTheCenter([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
console.log(swapTowardsTheCenter(['f1','f2','f3', 'c', 'b3', 'b2' ,'b1']));
```

result:

```
[ 'pizza', 42, 'Ada', 2, 'true' ]
[ 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 1 ]
[ 'b1', 'f2', 'b3', 'c', 'f3', 'b2', 'f1' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an approach with one variable for the left index and the length of the array, then you take the index and lenght to calculate the right index,

```js
function swap(array) {
    var l = array.length,
        i = 0;
    
    while (i < l / 2) {
        [array[i], array[l- 1- i]] = [array[l - i - 1], array[i]];
        i += 2;
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(swap(['true', 42, 'Ada', 2, 'pizza'])); // ['pizza', 42, 'Ada', 2, 'true']
console.log(swap([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));              // [6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 1]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

or you take two variables for the left and right index for swapping the items.

```js
function swap(array) {
    var left = 0,
        right = array.length - 1;
        
    while (left < right) {
        [array[left], array[right]] = [array[right], array[left]];
        left += 2;
        right -= 2;
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(swap(['true', 42, 'Ada', 2, 'pizza'])); // ['pizza', 42, 'Ada', 2, 'true']
console.log(swap([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));              // [6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 1]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter alternative utilizing ES6 Spread operator and destructuring assignment:

```
function swap(input) {
    var inputCopy = [...input];
    var [first, last] = [inputCopy.splice(0,1), inputCopy.splice(-1)];
    return  [...last, ...inputCopy, ...first];
}
```

Comment: That only works on very short arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Just adding my code here, Anyone might encounter this problem can try and utilize this code which just definitely does the job but way beyond the main goal of reversing the whole array instead of just reversing the first to last, second to the last-second and so on .

```js
function swapTowardCenter(arr){
    // Enter code below
    var newArr = [];
    for(var i = arr.length -1; i >= 0 ; i--){
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    console.log(newArr)
    // return newArr;
}

swapTowardCenter([true,42,"Ada",2,"pizza"])
```

Comment: You might want to reread the question (which isn’t about reversing the array)